# query to return required json format

Tags: sql, json, oracle, oracle-jet

i am using oracle jet and using a stacked bar chart which expects data in the format

```
 var barSeries = [{name: "Appointments", items: [3, 3]},
                         {name: "Login", items: [1, 6,3]},
                         {name: "Launch About", items: [4, 6]},
                         {name: "Resume Store Visit", items: [2, 6]},
                         {name: "Checkin", items: [9, 4]},
                         {name: "Visit History", items: [1, 4]},
                         {name: "Logout", items: [5, 7]},                     
                       ];
```

name value is the section within the bar and values in items is number of occurrence by date.

the question is what kind of sql query can i write on server side to return this json format?

the data on server side is in a single table as 
date, event name

Comment: Please provide your tables schema and state which columns are the ones shown in your json.

Comment: Here's a couple of options on building json's from a query: http://ora-00001.blogspot.ca/2010/02/ref-cursor-to-json.html

Answer (score 0):

It is not JSON format. It is a javascript object. It is an array of objects. Every object contains two fields. name & an array named items. You cannot write a server side code that returns in this format.

Whatever format you may get you can always parse and construct an object like this.

Learn Array.push and how create anonymous objects in javascript you will understand.

```
var baritems = [];
baritems.push({name: "Appointments", items: [3, 3]});
baritems.push({name: "Login", items: [1, 6,3]});
```

Above lines are equivalent to writing

```
var barSeries = [{name: "Appointments", items: [3, 3]},
                 {name: "Login", items: [1, 6,3]} ];
```